# Collation in variables

Tags: mysql, collation

After having many issues with ISO-8859-1 and reading a lot about collations I finally understand that I need to use charset `UTF8 collate utf8_unicode_ci`. So I configure my whole application with these changes and seems to be working smoothly until I needed to execute a manual query

```
SET @id := '10000016';
SET @invoice := (SELECT invoice FROM WAREHOUSE WHERE invoice_id = @id);
```

This query is giving me errors in MySQL Workbench with collation message:

```
Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

I can fix it using `SET @id := '10000016' collate utf8_unicode_ci;`, but this seems weird to me (to say least). I'm sure there's some missing step.

Maybe do I need to tweak something in my.cnf?

#### Other information

```
SELECT @@character_set_client; # utf8
SELECT @@character_set_results; # utf8
SELECT @@collation_connection; # utf8_general_ci
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is the datatype of `invoice_id`?  Where did `@tk` come from?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I mistype @id with @tk (edit my answer). invoice_id is utf8_unicode_ci. I assume workbench is interpreting the string `'10000016'` as utf8_general_ci?

Comment: Apparently that is the case.

Comment: Yes, but why. I though that workbench would change the string into the proper collate in the comparison. Or is collate utf8_unicode_ci some extravagant collate that I shouldn't be using?

Comment: See if running `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;` from workbench will solve the problem (until you logout).

Comment: 'general' is more simpleminded than 'unicode'.  'unicode_520' is a newer one based on a later Unicode standard.

Comment: Yes, your sollution `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;` works. How can I implement this in `my.cnf`? Thank you @RickJames

Comment: I'm not sure, but `collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci` might work.  See comments in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-g11n-excerpt/5.6/en/charset-server.html